# Finding the websphere version in java application

Tags: java, websphere

Its very common question to find the java version installed on the websphere, but how do we find the websphere version itself from an java application? My java application exists on the same server, please help.

I am aware of solution to add the version as the enviroment variable and reading it an app. But I am looking for a solution where in we don't have to add anything to WAS.

Comment: WAS should have admin console, just log on it and check !

Comment: I want to identify it through a java application not via console.

Comment: which java or from where to read? WAS is a app-server(container) used to deploy various app type. Use an jsp, servlet or what ever and echo env_var. Read doc and see what env_vars give you what wanted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347968/websphere-java-version , maybe usefull

Comment: https://www.dbappweb.com/2017/12/26/find-version-installed-ibm-websphere-application-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Server` MBean](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/Server.html) to programatically access product version information within your deployed application. The `serverVersion` attribute will provide the information you need and then some.  Within a scripting environment you have a couple options involving wsadmin objects: Use the `AdminTask` object to access the `serverVersion` attribute of the `server` MBean; or, use the `AdminControl.getNodeBaseProductVersion` command. Finally, from the command line use the  [versionInfo command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rins_versionInfo.html). -Regards.